# How to find the position of a star at a certain point during its orbit

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Hey I am trying to find a way to find the position of a Red Dwarf star that is in an elliptical orbit at a certain time during it's orbit. I know the Red Dwarf's semi major axis which is 3 AU (astronomical unit)  and it's period is 1896 days.

I've tried to do a simple using its orbit velocity and doing distance=velocity x time, but I wasn't getting answers that made sense. 
If anyone could set me on the right path of figuring this out would be great, thank you!

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.